# Discord.py not loading commands

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Hello everyone I am making a discord bot in discord.py using python 3.8. I have make some cogs and its not showing any issue bot whenever I type the load cog command or unload cog command its shows command not found. Only one of my cog is working another is not working please help me.

My Bot.py(main file)

```
import discord
import os
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import CommandNotFound


client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '#')


@client.command
async def load(ctx, extension):
    client.load_extension(f'cogs.{extension}')

@client.command
async def unload(ctx, extension):
    client.unload_extension(f'cogs.{extension}')

for filename in os.listdir('./cogs'):
    if filename.endswith('.py'):
        client.load_extension(f'cogs.{filename[:-3]}')



client.run('BOT TOKEN')
```

My First cog file main.py

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands


class main(commands.Cog):

    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client

    #Events
    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_ready(self):
        print('Bot is online.')

    # Commands
    @commands.command(name='ping',help='Sends the latency of the Bot')
    async def ping(self, ctx):
        await ctx.send(f'**Pong!** Latency: {round(self.client.latency * 1000)}ms')


def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(main(client))
```

My 2 cog file moderation.py

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands


class moderation(commands.Cog):

    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client

        @commands.command(name='clear', help='deletes no. of messages you give it')
        async def clear(ctx, amount = 1000):
            await ctx.channel.purge(limit=amount)

def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(moderation(client))
```

Answer (score 1):

Your indentation is wrong - you declared your command inside of your `__init__` instead of in your class itself.

```
def __init__(self, client):
    self.client = client

@commands.command(name='clear', help='deletes no. of messages you give it')
async def clear(ctx, amount = 1000):
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=amount)
```

Comment: Thank you very much I also have one more question the load and unload command is not working in Bot.py Its showing '''Ignoring exception in command None:
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound: Command "load" is not found'''
Please help

Comment: Your decorators are wrong, command decorators need brackets after them. `client.command` should be `client.command()`.